# How to share text on Skype

Tags: ios, swift, share, skype

I am working with sharing App, when I have to send some text to App like (whatsapp, gmail, skype, etc). All are working good except skype.

```
let urlSchema = "skype://?chat=hello"

let escapedString = 
urlSchema.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: 
.urlQueryAllowed)   
if UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: escapedString!)!){                
}else
{            
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: 
     "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510")!)   
}
```

It will open skype App, but without text, when I try with `UIActivityViewController` it will open app and share text as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are no using the `skype` URI does not support.
As in the [skype URI documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx) you can only set the topic:

```
let urlSchema = "skype:?chat&topic=hello"
```